# Вывод значения переменных вместе с текстом в С++

Tags: c++, строки, вывод, форматирование

В Python есть следующая возможность вывода данных:

```
i = 10
a = 555
print(f"Решение ном.{i}: {a}.") 

>> Решение ном.10: 555.
```

Можно ли сделать тоже самое в С++? То есть, вместе с текстом вывести значение переменных? Если да, то как это сделать? Как называется эта тема, чтобы найти про неё подробнее в интернете?

Comment: Использовать функции С `printf` или воспользоваться [`format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать функцию С `printf` или воспользоваться `format`, например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i = 10, a = 555;

    printf("Решение ном. %d: %d.\n",i,a);

    cout << format("Решение ном. {}: {}.\n",i,a);
}
```